Реализация привязки действий к элементам управления, созданным в процессе выполнения программы
Передо мной стоит задача разработать редактор электрических схем на Avalonia C#. На верхней панели необходимо расположить набор стандартных примитив, которые пользователь мог бы перетаскивать на кадр, расположенный ниже.
Так же необходимо иметь возможность перетаскивать с верхней панели на кадр кнопки. К кнопке, находящейся на кадре, необходимо иметь возможность прикрепить одно из перечисленных действий: открыть другой кадр, открыть окно в редакторе схем, вызвать метод библиотеки, подключенной к редактору схем. Функциональность упомянутой библиотеки состоит в том, чтобы посылать команды в другую программу.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как архитектурно реализовать привязывание команд (методов) к кнопкам, расположенным на кадре?

Canvas и контролы на нём.
